# Export all functions in imported header files

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, shared-libraries

I am building a dll file using cmake and c++ on windows. My project is composed of several header files, and one complete header file to be included in a different c++ project. The larger header file looks something like the following:

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"
...
```

I read that I have to use `__declspec(dllimport)` and `__declspec(dllexport)`, so I have used some ifdef statements like this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#    ifdef EXPORT
#        define API __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#        define API __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#elif
#    define API
#endif
```

My questions is: do I have to put this in every header file, or can I somehow do it for the header file as a whole? For example, like this:

```
#include API "header1.h"
#include API "header2.h"
#include API "header3.h"
...
```

(does not work, but is there something similar to this that does?)

Comment: You have to use the `API` macro for every symbol you wish to export/import. This is because the preprocessor and the `#include` directive doesn't work the way you seem to expect. When the preprocessor finds a valid `#include` directive, it basically insert the preprocessed header file contents of the file directly in place of the `#include` directive.

Comment: you may be interested by https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html

Comment: and kitware blog post: https://blog.kitware.com/create-dlls-on-windows-without-declspec-using-new-cmake-export-all-feature/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid this boilerplate. Most project simply put common code which defines the `API`-like macro to a dedicated header and `#include` it at start of each public header file.